# How can i make a "Download PDF" button inside of Odoo?

Tags: odoo, odoo-14, odoo-15, odoo-16

I have a api and this api returning a binary pdf.

This pdf is changing everytime when a request come and i don't want the store it.

Simply i want the create a button and this should trigger a function.

Function should be take my api response (binary pdf) and show this pdf to user in interface. (with download button)

Thanks for any suggestion

Answer (score 1):

I would write a controller to return the file, and put a button on the view or in the header with action to call the controller.

```py
from odoo.http import request, content_disposition, Controller


class MyController(Controller):
    
    @http.route('/download_file', auth='user', type='http')
    def download_file(self, id, **kw):
        # call the external API to retrieve the file
        file_content = requests.get('http://example.com/api/file').content

        # set the filename and content type
        filename = 'my_file.txt'
        content_type = 'text/plain'

        # send the file as a response to user and prompt them to download it
        return request.make_response(file_content,
            [('Content-Type', content_type),
             ('Content-Disposition', content_disposition(filename))])
```